# The entity Clients type is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I am using EF to perform CRUD currently Selecting records and passing it to View through View Models.

The table name and class name is also same then too can't understand that why this error is coming even after debugging it gives the same error.

View Model

```
namespace SingleVIewCrud.Models
{

public class tblClients
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class VMtblClient
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public  List<tblClients> tblClients { get; set; }

}
}
```

Db Set

```
public virtual DbSet<tblClients> Clients { get; set; }
```

Action

```
public ActionResult Home(int? id)
    {
        VMtblClient model = new VMtblClient();
        model.tblClients = db.Clients.ToList();    
        return View(model);
    }
```

Revised Code DbContext class,

```
public partial class SampleEntities1 : DbContext
{
    public SampleEntities1()
        : base("name=SampleEntities1")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<tblClient> tblClients { get; set; }


    public virtual DbSet<tblClients> tblClient { get; set; }
}
```

Action

```
public ActionResult Home(int? id)
    {
        VMtblClients model = new VMtblClients();
        var test = db.tblClient.ToList();    
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Where are you creating the object `db` ?

Comment: SampleEntities1 db = new SampleEntities1();  Below the controller

Comment: Can you share the db connection string and dbcontext class?

Comment: namespace SingleVIewCrud.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    
    public partial class SampleEntities1 : DbContext
    {
        public SampleEntities1()
            : base("name=SampleEntities1")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<tblClient> tblClients { get; set; }


        public virtual DbSet<tblClients> tblClientss { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Connection String <add name="SampleEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Emp.csdl|res://*/Models.Emp.ssdl|res://*/Models.Emp.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=test\MSSQLSERVER2014;initial catalog=Sample;user id=sa;password=pw;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: Sorry for the messy code

Comment: You could have edit your question with the code. Question, why do you have "public virtual DbSet<tblClient> tblClients { get; set; }", and   "public virtual DbSet<tblClients> tblClientss { get; set; }" two definitions?

Comment: In the first table am performing crud on a single view but later i came to know that its not the correct approach so now want to do the samw with View models thats why am not changing the existing functionality.created a new table with similar name

Comment: Even i renamed the table to some test name then too getting the same error

Comment: In your DbContext class there is no  definition for "Clients". So "db.Clients.ToList();" should not work. From where do you refer to "db", it has to be the dbcontext class, refer it with a using(var context = new SampleEntities1()){ context.tblClients.ToList();}.

Comment: Removing the virtual didn't work

Comment: Have edited the code under revised code.Partial class is auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

In your SampleEntities1 DbContext class there is no definition for "Clients". So "db.Clients.ToList();" should not work. From where do you refer to "db", it has to be the dbcontext class,

Try this code,

```
VMtblClient model = new VMtblClient();

using(var context = new SingleVIewCrud.Models.SampleEntities1())
{ 
   model.tblClients = context.tblClient.ToList();
}

return View(model);
```

Comment: Used the code in the action but getting the same error,cleaned the solution then too the same error.

Comment: It has to be "tblClient" not "tblClients" as you are referring to tblClient class. I edited the answer.

Comment: It is model.tblClients = context.tblClient.ToList();

Comment: Thanks for helping theres a confusing with the table name,will create a new table with some other name and implement your code.Leaving for office.

Comment: That's better, seesm like you have messed up the Entityframework configuration. Start with a fresh one! There has to be "Clients" class somewhere in your code, try to search it and see whether you can solve it.Good luck!